# Change Font color and size when booting into CLI ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, fonts

I was wondering if there was a way to increase font size and change font colour when booting into CLI.

### The font is small and white on black, I want it to change the font colour.

To get to the step where I want to change the font size and colour, I booted into Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

1.) Opened Terminal :
Typed Command : **"sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target"**, 
then
"**sudo reboot"** so that I was able to disable GUI From ubuntu.

After the reboot I was taken to a what I presume is a terminal or maybe tty1, but I am not quite sure. It reads **"Ubuntu 20.04 LTS User1-HP-Mini-110-3000 tty1"**
then 
**"user1-HP-Mini-110-3000 login:"**

From that I assumed I accomplished my goal of Disabling GUI from Ubuntu.

**My question though is how to change the font color and size on this screen?**

If anyone can help, that would be great. 
I am ready to provide any system details if needed.
Thanks

Comment: on what type of terminal are you having issues with font size, an xterm, an ssh session, the console?  For the first two, it's largely a software-controlled setting, and there is probably an option in the menus of whatever client you're using to set the font size.  For the console under Ubuntu, you can change the font with the console-setup from setupcon by trying, as root or using sudo, ```dpkg-reconfigure console-setup```

Comment: A good first step would be to describe the process you use to "boot into the CLI" in as much detail as possible. That's a generic phrase which could describe things as disparate as starting the system in run level 3 and selecting the recovery mode from the GRUB menu. Since all text modes default to a white on black font that appears somewhat small on modern monitor sizes, more information is needed to understand precisely the change you're trying to implement.

Comment: @PeterJ.Mello i think he refer to https://superuser.com/a/314061/973279, this post should be about tty0,2,3,4, etc..